# Adding custom attributes to GeoJSON with QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson

I have some GeoJSON data (originally GPX data) like below:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [
{"type": "Feature","properties":{"time":"2018-03-15T12:22:17.293Z","provider":"network","time_long":"1521116537293","accuracy":"21.507","altitude":"521.2000122070313"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[12.9734916,13.6980481]}}
,{"type": "Feature","properties":{"time":"2018-03-15T12:20:50.000Z","provider":"gps","time_long":"1521116450000","accuracy":"26.0","altitude":"601.0","bearing":"306.1","speed":"0.95"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[12.9732416,13.69785612]}}
}
```

I need to add two global level parameters:

```
start_time: 1521116537293
filename:  myfile.jpg
```

So that when I perform WFS calls in Javascript, I get two parameters from GeoJSON response in addition to above GPX point data.

Is it possible and supported in GeoJSON and if so how to do that in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [GeoJSON specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946), a `FeatureCollection` object has a single `features` object.  Any other additional elements are what the GeoJSON spec would call ["Foreign Members"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-6) and are not part of the spec.

"Foreign members" *may* be used in a GeoJSON document but support can vary across implementations and I don't think QGIS supports this.

So you *can* add your custom attributes, but you would probably have to implement the adding and handling of them.

Answer (score -1):

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
"start_time": 1521116537293,
"filename":  myfile.jpg,
"features": [
{"type": "Feature","properties":{"time":"2018-03-15T12:22:17.293Z","provider":"network","time_long":"1521116537293","accuracy":"21.507","altitude":"521.2000122070313"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[12.9734916,13.6980481]}}
,{"type": "Feature","properties":{"time":"2018-03-15T12:20:50.000Z","provider":"gps","time_long":"1521116450000","accuracy":"26.0","altitude":"601.0","bearing":"306.1","speed":"0.95"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[12.9732416,13.69785612]}}
}
```

You can do it as shown above.

Comment: Does Geojson standard support it and how to do in QGIS?